Where should a binary file that must be executed by another program be stored on a UNIX system?
I am writing a program that uses a library which requires that my program be called by a driver which initializes the environment etc first. This is done by passing the path of my executable (or just the name if it is stored in /bin) as an argument to the driver.
My program, if executed by the user on its own, would do nothing or fail, so I also provide a shell script that simply executes the driver with the binary (just a one-liner of [driver] [myprogram]), which can then be placed in /bin /usr/bin, etc to be called system-wide. I am uncertain of where to store my program's executable on the system though, as it should be somewhere that this shell script can access, but it by itself is not an executable, so none of the */bin options make sense there.
This is a similar situation that one would run into with .jar files that must be ran with java (and, in fact, most of the java applications on my system do the same approach with a shell script); however, while there is a /usr/share/java directory which seems standard for this sort of thing, I have not found an equivalent for other types of executables.
Looking at the FHS, there is a /usr/libexec directory for this sort of thing, but it is optional (and, in fact, my system doesn't have any such directory). While the install script for my program could create this directory if needed, I'm not sure if that is the best approach. I believe /usr/share could also be appropriate, but I am not sure.
